# $\left.\left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}\right)^n J_0(x)\right|_{x=0}={}$?

Tags: analysis, special-functions, bessel-functions

I am interested in determining a closed expression for the n-th derivative of the Bessel function of the first kind $J_0(x)$, centered in $x=0$:
\begin{equation}
\left.\left(\frac{\mathrm  d}{\mathrm d x} \right)^n J_0(x)\right|_{x=0}
\end{equation}
Can I compute it? If yes, how?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn't it trivial from the series definition of $J_0$? What is *your* definition of $J_0$?

Answer (score 4):

This proof uses operator methods.
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{t^n}{n!} \frac{d^n}{dx^n} J_0(x)\Big|_{x=0} =
\exp{\big(t\,\frac{d}{dx} \big)}  J_0(x) \Big|_{x=0} =  J_0(x+t) \Big|_{x=0} = J_0(t)=
$$
$$= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1/4)^n}{n!^2} t^{2n}$$
Equate coefficients of $t.$  Odd $n$ will yields zero coefficients.  Even coefficients imply 
$$ \frac{d^{2n}}{dx^{2n}} J_0(x)\Big|_{x=0} =  (-1/4)^n\frac{(2n)!}{n!^2}=(-1)^n2^{-2n}\binom{2n}{n}$$
Combining we have
$$ \frac{d^{n}}{dx^{n}} J_0(x)\Big|_{x=0} =  \frac{1+(-1)^n}{2} \, i^n\,2^{-n}\binom{n}{n/2}$$

Comment: seems to work great, do you have a bibliographic reference on this approach?

Comment: Isn't this circular: you use the power-series of $J_0(x)$ to derive the power-series of $J_0(x)$ (which the coefficients you compute really are)?

Comment: @ Vincent. exp(hd/dx)f(x)=f(x+h) is a very old formula. It can be thought of as a way to express the McLaurin expansion. I see it in my F.B. Hildebrand's Intro to Numerical Analysis, Ch.5, Dover ed., pg 181, (first ed. was 1956) but this cannot be the first time it was in a popular textbook.

Comment: @Winther  Not circular because I say nothing about $J_0(x)$ in the beginning step, only that I want to find $d^n/dx^n\,J_0(x)|_{x=0}.$  You can use the same trick for other functions, say, $\sin(x),$ and that first step would be the same, just $J_0(x) \to \sin(x).$  The information resides in the Taylor series for whatever function you decide to use, $J_0(x),\sin(x),$ etc., and that's in the last step.

Comment: @skbmoore thanks for the reference. I was not aware of this formula.

Answer (score 2):

The defining ODE of the zeroth order Bessel function is

$$x^2J_0''(x) + xJ_0'(x) + x^2J_0(x) = 0.$$

Solve this using the power-series method ([Frobenius method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method)): take the ansatz $J_0(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ and insert it into the ODE to get a recurrence relation for the $a_n$'s and solve this. With this solution in hand note that
$$\left.\frac{d^n}{dx^n}J_0(x)\right|_{x=0} = n! a_n$$
which gives you all the numbers you seek.

Comment: Thanks for all your responses and discussions. Regarding the answer above, I guess the recursion relations shall take as a seed the values of the lowest derivative(s) of J_0 in x=0?

Comment: @Graz Yes. The initial conditions are taken to be $J_0(0) = 1$ and $J_0'(0) = 0$ so $a_0 = 1$ and $a_1 = 0$ are the initial conditions to apply to the recurrence $a_{n+2}  = -\frac{a_n}{n^2}$.

Comment: (Sorry, small typo above. It should be $a_{n} = -\frac{a_{n-2}}{n^2}$)